# List in app widget

Tags: android, list, dynamic, android-appwidget

Is it possible to have a list with dynamic amount of items in app widget?

Comment: @Maragues: Actually, the answer is "No".

Comment: My wrong then, I didn't know what he was refering to by app widget. I was thinking on standard lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "list with dynamic amount of items", you mean a `ListView`, no.

If by "list with dynamic amount of items", you mean something inside of a `ScrollView`, no.

That is because neither `ListView` nor `ScrollView` are supported in app widgets. Also, app widgets are fixed size.

The only thing I have seen similar to what you describe probably uses a set of nested `LinearLayout` containers to set up a table, only some of whose cells are filled in (the rest are blank).

Answer (score 2):

At the time of this question, ListView's in AppWidgets were not possible. Now, you can by using `RemoteViews`. This example shows you how: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/StackWidget/index.html